# Postico GUI: How to setup an enum data type

Tags: postgresql, enums, postico

I'm using Postico's GUI interface to define a table, but I need an enum data type for a column. I'm not finding anything in the documentation or online that clearly denotes **how I setup the enum data type for use**. What I do find are various changelist statements about improved support for enums, but no details on how to actually set up that type.

[image]

I've tried putting in the `Type` column both of the following, hoping it would "trigger" or define it automatically...

- `enum`
- `enum ('Choice1', 'Choice2')`

... but both were rejected as invalid. I know that theoretically, I should be able to name and define the enum somewhere else and then use the name I defined in my data type here. But where/how do I define that in Postico?

Answer (score 1):

So I have not found a way to directly define it in the GUI (which is what I was wanting to know). If someone knows how, post here and I'll accept that answer. In the mean time, execute a SQL Query in Postico's query interface

[image]

to define the type, like so:

`CREATE TYPE your_type_name AS ENUM ('Choice1', 'Choice2');`

After that, then the GUI interface allows you to set the type on a column.